# $L^2$ operator norm and convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, compact-operators

**Question**: Consider $T_n : L^2[-\pi,\pi] \to L^2[-\pi,\pi]: u(x) \mapsto  \displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left( e^{\frac{x}{n} - \frac{y}{n}} \right) u(y) \; dy$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 1}$.

(a) Is $T_n$ compact? Self-adjoint?

(b) Calculate $\|T_n\|_{op}$.

(c) Does $T_n$ converge? If so, to what and in what (operator) sense?

**Solution**:

(a) Compactness - Notice that $T_n (u) (x) = e^{\frac{x}{n}} \displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-\frac{y}{n} } u(y) dy$, so ran$(T_n)$ is contained in the finite dimensional subspace spanned by $e^{x/n}$, meaning it's compact.

I calculated $T_n^*(u)(x) = \displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left( e^{\frac{y}{n} - \frac{x}{n}} \right) u(y) \; dy$, so it's not self-adjoint.

(b) I'm stuck here. I can use Cauchy Schwarz to show that $\|T_n\|_{op} \le \|K\|_{L^2[-\pi,\pi]}$, where $K(x,y) = e^{x/n-y/n}$. But any attempts at the reverse inequality have not been successful . . .

(c) It converges to the identity . . . I think strongly. Because of LDCT I can push a limit inside the integral. Uniformly, I'm unsure.

This is an old test problem, so part of why I ask this question is because I will have to answer similar questions on the exam in a timely manner. I could maybe mess around with part (c) for a while and come up with some function $u(y)$ that demonstrates non-uniform convergence, but I'm curious if there's a better way to go about it. I can't think of any examples now.

Please let me know if my work is correct or you can offer help. Thank you

Comment: Have you noticed that the very definition of $T_n$ is a convolution with $exp(y/n)\mathbb{1}_[-\pi,\pi]$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I did not notice. Hmmmm. How could this help? I don't encounter convolutions a lot.

Comment: You have guessed that the operator I was speaking about is $exp(y/n)\mathbb{1}_{[-\pi,\pi]}$. In general see for example this [thesis](etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/3917/1/thesis.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the norm we first make some heuristic argument. Looking at $T_n(u)(x)$, we see that this function is big, if the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-\frac{y}{n}}u(y)dy$ is big. When is this big? As $e^{-\frac{y}{n}}$ is big around $y = -\pi$, $u$ has to mass around $-\pi$. In the worst case, we have something like $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-\frac{y}{n}}u(y)dy \leq \|u\|_{L^2} e^{\frac{\pi}{n}}$.

Now $||T_n(u)||_{L^2} = \int_{-\pi}^{-\pi}e^\frac{x}{n}|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-\frac{y}{n}}u(y)dy|dx \leq \int_{-\pi}^{-\pi}e^\frac{x}{n}e^{\frac{\pi}{n}}\|u\|_{L^2}dx \leq \|u\|_{L^2} e^\frac{\pi}{n}2n \sinh{\frac{\pi}{n}}$.

The last $\sinh$ is just the $L^2$ norm of $e^\frac{x}{n}$. This formula is sharp by the heuristics, as one can take some sequence of $L^2$ functions converging to the $\delta$ distribution at $-\pi$.

For the third part, you have to consider that the identity is not compact, and norm convergence of compact operators are compact. Nevertheless we can pick some $u(x)$ which is orthogonal to $e^\frac{x}{n}$, then $\|T_n(u) - u\|_{L^2}\geq \|u\|_{L^2}$.

EDIT:

The limit is not the identity function. If $n\to \infty$, then $T_n(u)(x) \to \|u\|_{L^2}$, the constant function with value $\|u\|_{L^2}$. This is becuase $e^\frac{x}{n}$ converges **uniformly** to the constant $1$ function (at least on $[-\pi, \pi]$), and you can thus interchange limit and integral, without referencing LDCT.

Comment: I guess that the very last $||u|||_{L^2}$ is supposed to be $||u||_{L^2}$? BTW you can use `\|` instead of `||` to denote the norm.

Comment: Shoot, I meant something like the "identity integral" which would be $\|u\|_{L^2}$ indeed. In particular, since $e^{x/n - y/n} \to 1$ uniformly, and our interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ is bounded, we can immediately interchange limit and integral.

Comment: I think you forgot a squared so $\|T_n(u)\|_{L^2} = e^{2\pi /n} 2n \sinh( \pi/n)$, but the idea still stands. Can you explain the "sharp by heuristics" part? I believe you are just going off the first paragraph you wrote and creating a series of functions that takes most mass around $-\pi$. So maybe $f_n(x) = n \chi_{[-\pi,-\pi+1/n^2]}$ (of unit length) would work?

Comment: Never mind. When I use the $f_k(x)$ from my last comment I get $\|T_n (u_k)\|_{L^2} \stackrel{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

Comment: @user288742 The $f_n$ you defined works perfectly. I think you might have miscalculated something as $T_n(f_k)(x)= e^\frac{x}{n} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^\frac{-y}{n} f_n(y)dy =  e^\frac{x}{n} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi+1/n^2} e^\frac{-y}{n} f_n(y)dy \geq  e^\frac{x}{n}e^\frac{\pi -1/n^2}{n} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi+1/n^2}  f_n(y)dy =  e^\frac{x}{n}e^\frac{\pi -1/n^2}{n} \|f_n\|_{L^2}=e^\frac{x}{n}e^\frac{\pi -1/n^2}{n}.$

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer Indeed, I must have messed up. Thanks for the help Oles!